# how to prevent iterator invalidation in this case

Tags: visual-c++

need little help. here is what i want to do

```
std::list<int> mylist;
std::list<int>::iterator it;
it = mylist.begin();  

for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i)    
mylist.push_back(i); // 1 2 3 4 5

mylist.insert (it,10);   // 10 1 2 3 4 5 expected but output is 1 2 3 4 5 10
```

I am actually required to do something like this in my project.Is there a better way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You write the code `it = mylist.begin();`   after the

```
for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i)    
mylist.push_back(i); // 1 2 3 4 5
```

because it point to last index.

Answer (score 0):

Store the index instead of the iterator. That way no invalidation can happen.